# Making multiple GraphQL queries concurrently using Apollo's useQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a working example of a simple Apollo query that works fine using useQuery:

```
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(query, { variables: { fromDate: dates[0][0], toDate: dates[0][1] } });
  if (loading) return "Loading...";
  if (error) return <pre>{error.message}</pre>
  if (data) console.log(data.token)
  return <div>
    <p>{data.token[0].name}</p>
  </div>
```

As you may note, I'm only querying for the first tuple in an array of two-element arrays. I've reduced the array to the first few entries for illustration.

```
const dates = [
  ["2022-07-01T00:00:00+00:00", "2022-07-16T00:00:00+00:00"], 
  ["2022-07-16T00:00:00+00:00", "2022-08-01T00:00:00+00:00"], // July
  ["2022-08-01T00:00:00+00:00", "2022-08-16T00:00:00+00:00"],
  ["2022-08-16T00:00:00+00:00", "2022-09-01T00:00:00+00:00"], // August
  ["2022-09-01T00:00:00+00:00", "2022-09-16T00:00:00+00:00"]]
```

What would be the most efficient way to get the data from all the elements in the array, given that the useQuery hook can't be looped? I've seen examples for non-graphQL queries of people using Promise.all, but I get a React error when I try to recreate the example (Object not valid as a React child), and I'd still have to type the 25 useQuery in a row inside the Promise.

```
const res = await Promise.all([  
    useQuery(query, { variables: { fromDate: dates[0][0], toDate: dates[0][1] } }),
    useQuery(query, { variables: { fromDate: dates[1][0], toDate: dates[1][1] } }),
    useQuery(query, { variables: { fromDate: dates[2][0], toDate: dates[2][1] } }),
    ...
  ]);
  const data = res.map((res)=>res.data);
  console.log(data.flat());
  return <div>
    <p>Loaded</p>
  </div>
```

Do I just run 25 useQuery in a row with individual variables? Any productive help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have access to that API endpoint, maybe it is better to make one query that accepts multiple from/to dates and returns a single list of all that data.

Comment: I might end up having to do this at the database/query level using aliases and fragments.

Answer (score 1):

I ultimately resolved this at the query level by creating a monster query using aliases and fragments, bypassing the need for a React solution.